# Git track a remote branch using netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using Netbeans, and there is a feature call `Push to Upstream`. When I click it I get this message:

> No tracked remote branch specified for local master

Is there a way to track the remote branch in netbeans, or in the config file?

Here is my config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    bare = false
[remote "master"]
    url = https://github.com/TheColorRed/JGame.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/master/master
```

I don't have `git` installed on my computer, but Netbeans comes with a git package to do git operations. I don't really want to download git just to run one line, so is there a way in netbeans or in the config file to track a branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't have git installed on my computer

Yet, that remains the safest solution: simply [unzip the archive msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) (it you are on windows), and do a:

```
git branch -u master origin/master
```

Even [other users came to the same conclusion](http://enzam.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/how-to-solve-netbeans-error-no-tracked-remote-branch-specified-for-local-branch-name/).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe my solution for this problem seems to be too easy, but I had the same error and instead of using **Push to Upstream** you just have to use **Push** for your first commit. Afterwards you can select your remote repository/branch in Netbeans.

Comment: This hint from @Manuel helped me. There has been a bug report on Branches started locally: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231996

Answer (score 3):

We keep encountering this problem and it's enough to make you mad. I've had to re-clone the repo several dozzen times by now.

Thanks to @Damian for their solution. I was a little lost in their answer, so after figuring it out thought I'd share how we were able to solve this:

- In Netbeans, under the top menu, click `Team` > `Repository` > `Repository Browser`
- Under the repository causing you problem, expand `Branches` > `Local`
- Find the branch w/ a bolded name (that's your active branch) - Ours was called "(no branch)"
- Right-click on the branch, and click `Set Tracked Branch`
- Select the branch you want - In our case, it's called "origin/master".

Answer (score 0):

This issue can now be solved entirely within the NetBeans interface. First, right click on the project and select `Git > Branch/Tag > Switch to Branch...`

Then select the desired branch (e.g. "`origin/master`"), and select `Checkout as New Branch`.

This will create a local copy of that branch, so assuming you checked out the master branch, you will now see `master` in addition to `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just go to `Team > Repository > Repository Browser`; in the window that opens find your local branch, right-click it and select `Setup Tracked Branch`

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch doesn't track remote branch. You can bind them in command line

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master
```

Or in GUI:

1. Open `Git Repository Browser`
2. Select your project -> `Braches` -> `Local` -> `master` (or whatever branch you want)
3. Right click, `Setup Tracked Branch`